# How to fix offset warning running a GAM in R's MGCV package?

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I am trying to run a GAM using MGCV. 
When I include offset:

```
gam1 <- gam(Presence~s(Spd)+offset(effort_m), family=binomial, data=porp)
```

I receive the following warning:

Warning messages:

```
1: In newton(lsp = lsp, X = G$X, y = G$y, Eb = G$Eb, UrS = G$UrS, L = G$L,  :
  Fitting terminated with step failure - check results carefully
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
3: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: Is the `effort_m` variable on the logit scale? Typically it should be on the same scale as the link function, which in this case is the logit (log-odds). The first message is indicating that the optimisation failed in a known way; the next step down the likelihood function couldn't happen (probably made things worse, even after trying step halving), but the model hadn't converged. The other two warnings suggest problems with the fit that are commonly encountered in logit models. I'd check that the offset is specified correctly and refit and see what warnings remain.

Comment: @GavinSimpson the effort_m variable is actual numbers for each line of the data, and thank you.